# Messages sent to Facebook returning with POL-P8

Tags: facebook, email, facebook-messages

We have a desktop system that sends various e-mails to the users. These users have the option to choose to receive a copy of all these e-mails in his/her Facebook message inbox and we do this by sending a copy of the e-mail to the user's @facebook address.

For some time, this was working with no problems but recently a client reported that some of the messages sent to the user's Facebook address were failing and returning.

After analyzing the returned message, we found that the diagnostic code was "POL-P8":

```
554 5.7.1 POL-P8
http://postmaster.facebook.com/response_codes?ip=143.106.10.159#pol-m
Message refused (in reply to end of DATA command)
```

Looking at the code description page (http://postmaster.facebook.com/response_codes?ip=143.106.10.159#pol-m), we found that this particular code translates as "The message does not comply with Facebook's abuse policies and will not be accepted.", which seems to tell us that the message was considered spam and, therefore, not sent.

Still, we don't know exactly why this is happening. It doesn't appear to be related to the message content, since we tried manually sending an e-mail with the exact same content to the @facebook address and it was sent and received with no problems. We also thought that the problem could be caused by a large number of messages being sent to the user's inbox in a short period of time, but we also weren't able to reproduce this.

I did not find any detailed information about compliance to the "Facebook abuse policies" so I am a bit lost on what could be the problem and what could be done... any help someone can give me will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you figure it out?? I am facing the same problem...

Comment: Not really... I didn't receive any response from Facebook support and the only information I found that could be related to the problem is this:
http://postmaster.facebook.com/reputation_and_authentication

It says that the mail domain should use SPF or DKIM to authenticate emails. Because the problem was in a client's environment, I figured that could be the problem, that their mail server didn't use any of those methods.

Comment: Estoy también en el mismo punto... hablaré con el administrador...
Muchas gracias